# ¿Tiene sentido «pulgar arriba»?

Tags: jerga-internet, cultura-de-masas

[Aqui](https://emojiterra.com/es/pulgar-hacia-arriba/) dice «pulgar **hacia** arriba» para describr el emoji.

Me pregunta si sería incorrecto describirlos como «pulgar arriba» y «pulgar abajo».

¿Se necesita usar «hacia» o puede ser opcional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No habría necesidad de poner la palabra "**hacia**" (es una precisión opcional) porque en castellano dos palabras resultan suficientemente claras para describir ambos gestos:

> = pulgar arriba /
>  = pulgar abajo

Como ejemplo puede verse el empleo (sin *hacia*) hecho en el [Diccionario de gestos: España e Hispanoamérica, Volume 1](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=O-dgAAAAMAAJ&dq=%22pulgar%20arriba%22&source=gbs_book_other_versions)

[image: pulgar arriba]